# "No such file" Include issue with Boost dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost, g++, boost-dynamic-bitset

I'm trying to use Boost's Dynamic_bitset class for a project, and I (believe I) have taken whichever subset of files I needed from the complete library. Now I'm doing an

`#include "boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp"` inside my manager.cpp file, and when compiling I get this:

```
In file included from manager.cpp:4:0:
boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp:15:51: fatal error: boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp: No such file or directory
```

The file ierarchy inside the project folder goes like this:

```
proj/extras.h
proj/Makefile~
proj/manager.cpp
proj/boost
proj/boost/limits.hpp
proj/boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp
proj/boost/mpl
proj/boost/mpl/if.hpp
proj/boost/mpl/has_xxx.hpp
proj/boost/iterator.hpp
proj/boost/static_assert.hpp
proj/boost/dynamic_bitset
proj/boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp
proj/boost/dynamic_bitset/config.hpp
proj/boost/config
proj/boost/config/select_platform_config.hpp
proj/boost/config/select_compiler_config.hpp
proj/boost/config/user.hpp
proj/boost/config/suffix.hpp
proj/boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp
proj/boost/dynamic_bitset_fwd.hpp
proj/boost/config.hpp
proj/boost/type_traits
proj/boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp
proj/boost/type_traits/is_pointer.hpp
proj/boost/type_traits/remove_pointer.hpp
proj/boost/type_traits/remove_const.hpp
proj/boost/type_traits/is_base_and_derived.hpp
proj/boost/type_traits/detail
proj/boost/type_traits/detail/bool_trait_def.hpp
proj/boost/type_traits/detail/yes_no_type.hpp
proj/boost/pending
proj/boost/pending/integer_log2.hpp
proj/boost/detail
proj/boost/detail/limits.hpp
proj/boost/detail/dynamic_bitset.hpp
proj/boost/detail/workaround.hpp
proj/boost/lowest_bit.hpp
proj/Makefile
proj/generator.cpp~
proj/generator.cpp
```

This same project compiles fine on my university's linux systems(g++ 4.2.4 there but I doubt it matters), but fails to do so (with the above error) on my Ubuntu laptop. Why isn't it finding the file since it evidently exists?

All my includes are as such:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp"
#include <cmath>
#include <list>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "extras.h"
```

compilation is done simply with

`g++ -o manager manager.c`
or
`g++ -Iboost -o manager manager.c`

if I want to explicitely include the (local..) folder

Comment: And your include directory points at `boost/dynamic_bitset`?

Comment: Hm, the boost lib is on the source folder itself, I shouldn't have to declare it elsewhere too, should I? I did try compiling with the -i option and explicitely including the boost folder, but I got the same error

Comment: Ah, hang on, sorry. Are you using "..." or <...> for your `#include`? The former means "look in your local include directories first", the latter means "this is a system include, so look in the system directories. Typically, the current directory is not part of "system incldue directories". In other words, you should have `#include "..."`, not `#include <...>` in your code.

Comment: I'm already using `#include "..."` instead of `<...>`

Comment: Perhaps you could post your actual code [about 5 lines either side] and the flags for your compile?

Comment: added the includes and my compilation attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-I .
```

At least if you are compiling in the same directory that contains boost.

You wrote -Iboost and #include "boost/…". So it looks in ./boost if there is a boost subdirectory.

Comment: Ehh, you're right, that's the correct way. However I don't understand why it needed an explicit declaration of the source folder in order to include the headers requested from within the original dynamic_bitset header (which was found without the need for -I).